# Select Diagonal Elements of a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Consider the following matrix in MATLAB:

01 02 03 04 05 06 07

08 09 10 11 12 13 14

15 16 17 18 19 20 21

22 23 24 25 26 27 28

29 30 31 32 33 34 35

36 37 38 39 40 41 42

43 44 45 46 47 48 49

I have to generate directional variograms for such 7 x 7 windows(moving) of an image. I will use `nlfilter` for the process but for developing the function to calculate variograms I am not able to decide how to select elements in the window. For example when I consider the central value 25, in EW direction I have to consider only 25, 26, 27 and 28; in NE direction I have to consider only 25, 19, 13 and 07 when the lag chosen is 1. Is there any standard command to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to get these elements yourself easily:

```
A = [01 02 03 04 05 06 07
     08 09 10 11 12 13 14
     15 16 17 18 19 20 21
     22 23 24 25 26 27 28
     29 30 31 32 33 34 35
     36 37 38 39 40 41 42
     43 44 45 46 47 48 49];

c = (size(A)+1)/2;
EW = A(c(1),c(2):end)
NE = diag(A(c(1):-1:1,c(2):end))
```

Just write this code in a function (preferably an m-file), perform your operation and pass the result back.

The `diag` function returns the diagonal elements of a matrix (or returns a diagonal matrix when passed a vector).

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it like this:

```
A = eye(5);
v = A(1:size(A,1)+1:end);
```

resulting in

```
v = [1 1 1 1 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is Generic matrix solution (not for MATLAB)
suppose matrix AxB =

```
[01 AA 03 04 05 06 07
 08 09 AA 11 12 13 AA
 AA 16 17 AA 19 AA 21
 22 AA 24 25 AA 27 28
 AA 30 AA 32 33 34 35
 36 AA 38 AA 40 41 42
 43 44 AA 46 AA 48 49];
```

in this matrix we want to search continuously  3 times appearence of AA diagonally.

Solution:-
step 1
for whole matrix we have to create 4 seperate for loops to search the appearence of AA continuously 3 times

[image]

i am adding method through which a user can search all loop and can find the item.

```
 local function check_win( matrx_table)

local counter = 1
local term = "AA"
local D = 1

-- for horizontal check for win---
for i = 1, no_rows, 1 do
    for j= 1, no_Columns, 1 do
        if((j+1) <= no_Columns) then             
            if(table_mXn[i][j] == term and table_mXn[i][j+1] == term)then
                counter = counter + 1;
            else
                counter = 1
            end               
            if(counter == 3)then
                return counter
            end               
        end
    end             
end

counter = 1
-- for vertical check for win--
for i = 1, no_Columns, 1 do
    for j= no_rows, 1, -1 do
        if((j-1) >= 1) then             
            if(table_mXn[j][i] == term and table_mXn[j-1][i] == term)then
                counter = counter + 1;
            else
                counter = 1
            end    
            if(counter == 3)then
                return counter
            end               
        end
    end             
end

counter = 1
D = 1
-- for diagonol  left half check for win in figure loop 1--
for m = 1, no_rows, 1 do
    D = 1
    for i =m, no_rows,1 do
        if(i+1 <= no_rows and D+1 <= no_Columns)then
            if(table_mXn[i][D] == term and table_mXn[i+1][D+1] == term)then
                counter = counter + 1;
                print("hhhhh")
            else
                counter = 1
            end               
            if(counter == 3)then
                return counter
            end     
            D = D + 1
        end
    end
end

counter = 1
D = 1
-- for diagonol  right half check for win in figure loop 2--
for m = 1, no_rows, 1 do
    D = m
    for i =1, no_rows,1 do
        if(i+1 <= no_rows and D+1 <= no_Columns)then
            if(table_mXn[i][D] == term and table_mXn[i+1][D+1] == term)then
                counter = counter + 1;
                print("hhhhh")
            else
                counter = 1
            end               
            if(counter == 3)then
                return counter
            end     
            D = D + 1
        end
    end
end

counter = 1
D = 1
-- for diagonol  left half check for win in figure loop 3--
for m = 1, no_rows, 1 do
    D = no_Columns
    for i =m, no_rows,1 do
        if(i+1 <= no_rows and D-1 >= 1)then
            if(table_mXn[i][D] == term and table_mXn[i+1][D-1] == term)then
                counter = counter + 1;
                print("hhhhh")
            else
                counter = 1
            end               
            if(counter == 3)then
                return counter
            end     
            D = D - 1
        end
    end
end

counter = 1
D = 1
-- for diagonol  left half check for win in figure loop 4--
for m = no_Columns, 1, -1 do
    D = m
    for i =1, no_rows,1 do
        if(i+1 <= no_rows and D-1 >= 1)then
            if(table_mXn[i][D] == term and table_mXn[i+1][D-1] == term)then
                counter = counter + 1;
                print("hhhhh")
            else
                counter = 1
            end               
            if(counter == 3)then
                return counter
            end     
            D = D - 1
        end
    end
end

end
```

now you can call this method any where in class and can check in that matrix the searchable item is available or not in repeatedly order Horizontally, Vertically and diagonally.