# Selecting Principal Diagonal Elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

In the matrix shown below how can I select elements 01, 09, 17 and 25. From [Egon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514071/egon) answer to my earlier question [Select Diagonal Elements of a Matrix in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528062/select-diagonal-elements-of-a-matrix-in-matlab) I am able to select the central value 25 using `c = (size(A)+1)/2;` but I am wondering how to select above mentioned elements in NW direction.

```
A = [01 02 03 04 05 06 07
     08 09 10 11 12 13 14
     15 16 17 18 19 20 21
     22 23 24 25 26 27 28
     29 30 31 32 33 34 35
     36 37 38 39 40 41 42
     43 44 45 46 47 48 49];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diag` to get elements on the diagonal.

```
diagA = diag(A)
```

You can restrict this to the elements from the top left to the middle with

```
n = ceil(size(A, 1) / 2)
diagA(1:n)
```

Comment: I assumed that `A` was square.  If not, then you need to clarify further what you want.

Comment: `A` will be always be square in my case. `A` is the moving window which I use in Image Processing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511). If you have an N-by-N matrix, you can select the elements you want as follows:

```
values = A(1:N+1:ceil((N^2)/2));
```